# Block and inline elements within block element

Tags: html, css, specifications

I thought that elements can contain block and inline at the same time, but [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#block-level0) says here that this is not so.

> A block-level box may contain either line boxes or block-level boxes, but not both. If necessary, any line boxes that belong to this box's element are wrapped in one or more (as few as possible) anonymous boxes with a ‘display’ of ‘block’.

Or am I wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inline anonymous boxes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823693/inline-anonymous-boxes)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Chris - I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. Although both questions quote the same piece of CSS spec, the actual question and answers focus on anonymous inline boxes, whereas this question  is actually about anonymous block boxes.

Comment: @Alohci, hmm maybe. Though they seem closely related enough. At the very least it's a useful link. :)

Comment: @Serzh - The important thing to grasp here is that an element is not a box. An element is an HTML or XML concept, a box is a CSS concept. The rendering of a single element may result in the construction of zero, one, or many boxes.

Answer (score 1):

so understand it this way...

block cant contain both block and inline ...

but if you put them... then to adhere to above rule inline elements should be enclosed in anonymous boxes(as few as possible)

just above the line you have posted in your question you can see

> An anonymous box, informally, is a box that cannot be addressed with CSS selectors. All its properties, except for ‘display’, have their default values (either the initial value or inherited). Anonymous boxes are created when the CSS box model requires a child box with a certain value for ‘display’, but the child actually has a different value. In that case an anonymous box of the right kind is created and wraps the child (or children)

Comment: I looked at all the examples of the markup in the specification of HTML4 and saw that the text content is placed in anonymous boxes, and inline elements are always wrapped in a paragraph.

Comment: @Serzh can you link me to spec where paragraph is there , wrapping inline elements

Comment: 17.4.2, 17.10 for example.[HTML 4.01 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-FORM)

Comment: [link2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#edef-IMG) 13.6.1. And so on. As you can see, all inline elements are wrapped with paragraph